# "DO" macro variable-definition not being bound

Tags: common-lisp

I have written a function using the DO macro (using  Peter Seibel's book as reference) but for some reason, when I compile my function:

```
(defun test ()
  (do ((n 2 (1+ n))
       (m 1 (1+ m))
       (a (1+ n))
       (b (1+ m))
       (c (+ n m)))
      ((= n 10) (* a b c))
      (print (* a b c))))
```

I get the following warning messages:

```
WARNING: in TEST in lines 1..10 : N is neither declared nor bound,
         it will be treated as if it were declared SPECIAL. 
WARNING: in TEST in lines 1..10 : M is neither declared nor bound,
         it will be treated as if it were declared SPECIAL. 
WARNING: in TEST in lines 1..10 : N is neither declared nor bound,
         it will be treated as if it were declared SPECIAL. 
WARNING: in TEST in lines 1..10 : M is neither declared nor bound,
         it will be treated as if it were declared SPECIAL.
```

When I try to execute `test`, it says that `n` has no value.

I am under the impression that the order of binding doesn't matter, but I tried rearranging it anyway and still received the same result.

**What am I missing here?**

I am using CLISP 2.49

Comment: The bindings created by `DO` are not visible to the init-forms in that `DO`. You might want `DO*` instead, but I'm not sure what the loop is supposed to do. The variables `A`, `B` and `C` don't have step-forms, so their values don't ever change. Maybe you're missing init-forms for those?

Comment: @jkiiski Thanks for the comment. I didn't know that they weren't available in the init-form. I figured since I could use them in the step form, it would be available everywhere :/
As for the purpose of the loop, I removed the body and return value for the sake of the question. It makes sense in the context! What would you suggest I do to work around the init form restriction?

Comment: Using `DO*` instead of `DO` should work, unless you need the step-forms to all be evaluated before any assignments (which doesn't seem to be the case, unless you have more variables not shown in the code).

Comment: @jkiiski Thanks a lot for the answer. You should write a summary of the comments as an answer so I can give you some credit for it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`DO` evaluates all init-forms for the variables before creating any variable bindings. That means the bindings are not visible to init-forms in the same `DO`.

The code should work using `DO*` instead, although the output isn't very interesting since `A`, `B` and `C` never change.

```
(defun test ()
  (do* ((n 2 (1+ n))
        (m 1 (1+ m))
        (a (1+ n))
        (b (1+ m))
        (c (+ n m)))
       ((= n 10) (* a b c))
    (print (* a b c))))

(test)
; 18 
; 18 
; 18 
; 18 
; 18 
; 18 
; 18 
;=> 18
```

`DO*` is otherwise the same as `DO`, but it evaluates and establishes the bindings one by one, so you can refer to the previous variables in the init-forms. The same is done when updating the variables with the step-form.